# Running Java program at regular intervals

Tags: java

I need to run a Java program periodically say once ever 2 hours. How do I do this in Linux(Ubuntu)?

Comment: @Trevor http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Answer (score 4):

You should add an entry to crontab:

```
0 */2 * * * script.sh
```

In script.sh you should have something like:

```
#! /bin/sh
java -jar <your jar file>
```

Comment: It is a .java file. What do I do?

Comment: compile it with `javac` and run it with `java`.

Answer (score 1):

how about a [cron-job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) ?

> Cron is a system daemon used to
>   execute desired tasks (in the
>   background) at designated times.

More information can be found by typing in Ubuntu:

```
man crontab
```

**[or here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)**

Answer (score 1):

Use cron.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 1):

Use a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

Cron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Will let you launch your Java task at a set interval.

Answer (score 0):

For a nice interface to cron you can use:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule`

Answer (score 0):

A pure Java solution would use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).  That'll work on any operating system.  It'll have the added advantage of allowing you to send alert e-mails if an exception is caught.  It'll fit nicely into your logging/monitoring framework.